# perf ftrace falis to start

Tags: kernel, perf, ftrace

When try to start `perf ftrace` I get following error

```
write '' to tracing/tracing_cpumask failed: Invalid argument
failed to reset ftrace
```

However my kernel configured ftrace enabled and `trace-cmd` ftrace frontend also works as well.

---

For some reason in the `perf/builtin-ftrace.c` file in the `write_tracing_file` function I get

```
static int __write_tracing_file(const char *name, const char *val, bool append)
{
        char *file;
        int fd, ret = -1;
        ssize_t size = strlen(val);
```

I got `val` == an empty string, therefore `size` == 0

Then at the following section

```
if (write(fd, val_copy, size + 1) == size + 1)
                ret = 0;
        else
                pr_debug("write '%s' to tracing/%s failed: %s\n",
                         val, name, str_error_r(errno, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf)));
```

I got `size = 0` and which not ok. So something wrong with the CPU mask part but I have no clue what.

---

**Edit:** looks like its work with multicore system without problem, but not in single core system. Strange...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue somehow. Installed all the dependencies of `perf` including `libnuma-dev` etc. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Because perf version is not matched with current kernel.

if you install perf by yum. it will install the newest verison perf. you need download the matched perf from web and install it.